# Group consecutive alike elements

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and here's what I want to do :
[image]

So far only compiler errors :

```
groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems (x:xs) = 
    let (a,b) = span (<= x) xs
    in a : (groupElems b)
```

Thank you.

Error :

```
Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘<=’
from the context (Eq a)
  bound by the type signature for groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

Comment: Please post the error you obtain. Furthermore instead of simply stopping with "there are compiler errors", it would be nice to show what you think the errors mean. Usually a compiler aims to be descriptive about what the errors are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler says:

> ```
> Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘<=’
> from the context (Eq a)
>   bound by the type signature for groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
> ```

What the Haskell compiler aims to say is that you use `<= x` om your code, but the `<=` function is *not* part of the `Eq` typeclass: if we ask where `<=` originates from, we get:

```
Prelude> :i (<=)
class Eq a => Ord a where
  ...
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
infix 4 <=
```

So we can solve the issue by using the `Ord` typeclass: it means that the elements are ordered. But based on your examples this is *not* what you want. If we use `Ord a` as type constraint, like:

```
groupElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems (x:xs) = 
    let (a,b) = span (<= x) xs
    in a : (groupElems b)
```

A second problem is that we *call `span` on the `xs` list. `xs` is the *tail* of the list. So that means we will not take the head into account. We can alter this by using an alias `@` and process the entire list `xa`:

```
groupElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems xa@(x:_) = 
    let (a,b) = span (<= x) xa
    in a : (groupElems b)
```

we will obtain:

```
GHci > groupElems []
[]
GHci > groupElems [1,2]
[[1],[2]]
GHci > groupElems [1,2,2,2,4]
[[1],[2,2,2],[4]]
GHci > groupElems [1,2,3,2,4]
[[1],[2],[3,2],[4]]
```

Note that the last test case is not correct. That is because both `3` and `2` satisfy the `<= 3` predicate.

In case you want to group by *equality*, you should use the `(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` function:

```
groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems xa@(x:_) = 
    let (a,b) = span (== x) xa  -- use == instead of <=
    in a : (groupElems b)
```

which then produces:

```
GHci > groupElems []
[]
GHci > groupElems [1,2]
[[1],[2]]
GHci > groupElems [1,2,2,2,4]
[[1],[2,2,2],[4]]
GHci > groupElems [1,2,3,2,4]
[[1],[2],[3],[2],[4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler says that `a` must be an instance of `Ord` typeclass, because of using `<=`. So you can correct your code to this:

```
groupElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

But if you still need to use `Eq`, you can use `==` instead of `<=` and the code will work.

I also noticed, that your version of code returned `[1, [], [3]]` on `[1,2,2,3,3]` example, because you passed `xs` instead of the whole list.

```
groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupElems [] = []
groupElems all@(x:xs) =
    let (a,b) = span (== x) all
    in a : (groupElems b)
```

By the way, there's [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function in `Data.List` module that does exactly what you're going to achieve

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is [Data.List.group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group);

```
Prelude> Data.List.group [1,2,2,2,4]
[[1],[2,2,2],[4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are constraining your function so that `a` must be of class `Eq`. However, the function `<=` belongs to the `Ord` typeclass. Try changing the function annotation to this:

```
groupElems :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

Comment: thanks , that got me moving but the book exercise give me this signature groupElems :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]

Comment: In that case, why are you trying to compare less-than-or-equal-to? Why not just compare for equality?